# Importing Firestore Documents From Firebase Cloud Storage

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

**Is there a way to import specific Firestore Database Documents under an exported Collection from Firebase Cloud Storage?**

## Observed

After creating a JavaScript AppEngine Cron Job according to the [Schedule Export](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/schedule-export) documentation there does not seem to be a way to import specific Documents, only Collections.

## Expected

*In-Short*: The ability to export a specified Document representing a user.

The Firestore database of the app is currently structured with a *users* Collection at the highest level, and then a Document representing the user containing meta data, saved content, etc. A daily Cron Job has been scheduled with the documentation above in order to back up all of the Firestore data including the user data in the event users' data is inadvertently corrupted during development or maliciously in an attack.

However, from the [Import specific collections](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/export-import#import_specific_collections) documentation it appears only a Collection can be imported.

**Existing Data Structure**

[image: screen shot 2019-01-25 at 5 25 25 pm]

- users *collection*

  - user_one *document*

    - actions *collection*
       ...
    - categories *collection*
       ...
    - user data fields
  - user_two *document*
      ...

## Potential Solution if Importing Document Impossible

Refactoring the Firestore Database structure to add additional layers of Collections/Documents in order for each User to be represented by a unique Collection. The downside with the new data structure is you have a unnecessary additional `users` *document* 2nd level.

**New Data Structure**

- users *collection*

  - users *document*

    - user_one *collection*

      - actions *document*
        ...
      - categories *document*
        ...
      - user data *document* w/ fields
        ...
    - user_two collection
      ...

Comment: Your terminology is confusing here  "Firebase Storage" deprecated term and is used to discuss Firebase SDKs build on top of Google Cloud Storage.  It seems you are not using that here.  Please edit your question to use the terms "Firestore" or "Realtime Database" as you are using them here.

Comment: @DougStevenson, I edited the title in order to make it clear I am discussing _Firebase Cloud Storage_ as I am referring to Firebase SDKs build on top of Google Cloud Storage in this post. The result of the [Schedule data export](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/schedule-export) documentation is Firestore data exported to Cloud Storage. I am then discussing how to import the Cloud Storage data at a later time. For instance backing up user data from Firestore and being able to import the user's collection/document from Cloud Storage if there is an issue in the future.

Comment: @DougStevenson Update: I ran an experiment outlined [here](https://github.com/firebase/snippets-node/issues/32#issuecomment-459801339) and found that when importing an entire Firestore Database from Firebase Cloud Storage the **Document** data of a given user after the time of the snapshot will be overwritten whereas new **Collection** data from after the time of the snapshot will persist.